# tf.function with input_signature and optional python non-Tensor parameter to force retracing

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

[TensorFlow version 2.14.0; I'm experimenting in Colab.]

I have a function that uses `tf.pad` to pad an input tensor along the last dimension by the specified amount. The padding specification is a tensor with a fixed shape (1, 2). My goal is to generalise the function to an arbitrary rank of the tensor being padded. Let's start with a naīve implementation. In all of the following examples,

**Common Setup**

```py
import tensorflow as tf

t_padding = tf.constant([[2,3]], dtype='int32')
t = tf.constant([
  [[111, 112, 113, 114], [121, 122, 123, 124]],
  [[211, 212, 213, 214], [221, 222, 223, 224]]], 'float32')
```

The shape of `t` is (2, 2, 4).

The `@tf.function` decorator is not strictly required here, but I'm adding it to show that the shape of the input tensor is captured with exact dimensions, and this causes re-tracing for every shape of input. Note that baking `mode='symmetric'` into the graph is a *desired* effect: the whole model uses the same padding mode.

**Example 1**

```py
@tf.function(reduce_retracing=True)  # NOTE: reduce_retracing has no effect.
def pad_last_dim(x, padding, mode='symmetric'):
  print('=== pad_last_dim is being traced.')
  ext_pad = tf.concat([tf.zeros((tf.rank(x)-1, 2), dtype=padding.dtype), padding], 0)
  x_padded=tf.pad(x, ext_pad, mode)
  return x_padded

_ = pad_last_dim(t, t_padding)
print('\n', pad_last_dim.pretty_printed_concrete_signatures())
```

```
=== pad_last_dim is being traced.

 pad_last_dim(x, padding, mode=symmetric)
  Args:
    x: float32 Tensor, shape=(2, 2, 4)
    padding: int32 Tensor, shape=(1, 2)
  Returns:
    float32 Tensor, shape=(None, None, None)
```

It's evident that the exact shape of `t` had been captured. Calling the function with shapes (2, 2, 3) and (2, 4) causes re-tracing:

```py
_ = pad_last_dim(t[:,:,1:], t_padding)
_ = pad_last_dim(t[1], t_padding)
print('\n', pad_last_dim.pretty_printed_concrete_signatures())
```

```
WARNING:tensorflow:5 out of the last 5 calls to <function pad_last_dim at 0x7ae7b4188280> triggered tf.function retracing. Tracing is expensive and the excessive number of tracings could be due to (1) creating @tf.function repeatedly in a loop, (2) passing tensors with different shapes, (3) passing Python objects instead of tensors. For (1), please define your @tf.function outside of the loop. For (2), @tf.function has reduce_retracing=True option that can avoid unnecessary retracing. For (3), please refer to https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function#controlling_retracing and https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function for  more details.
WARNING:tensorflow:6 out of the last 6 calls to <function pad_last_dim at 0x7ae7b4188280> triggered tf.function retracing. Tracing is expensive and the excessive number of tracings could be due to (1) creating @tf.function repeatedly in a loop, (2) passing tensors with different shapes, (3) passing Python objects instead of tensors. For (1), please define your @tf.function outside of the loop. For (2), @tf.function has reduce_retracing=True option that can avoid unnecessary retracing. For (3), please refer to https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function#controlling_retracing and https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function for  more details.

=== pad_last_dim is traced.
=== pad_last_dim is traced.

 pad_last_dim(x, padding, mode=symmetric)
  Args:
    x: float32 Tensor, shape=(2, 2, 4)
    padding: int32 Tensor, shape=(1, 2)
  Returns:
    float32 Tensor, shape=(None, None, None)

pad_last_dim(x, padding, mode=symmetric)
  Args:
    x: float32 Tensor, shape=(2, 2, None)
    padding: int32 Tensor, shape=(1, 2)
  Returns:
    float32 Tensor, shape=(None, None, None)

pad_last_dim(x, padding, mode=symmetric)
  Args:
    x: float32 Tensor, shape=<unknown>
    padding: int32 Tensor, shape=(1, 2)
  Returns:
    float32 Tensor, shape=<unknown>
```

It's surprising that the new traces contain `<unknown>` and `None`, but surprising is not the same as helpful. The obvious solution to the re-tracing and shapes going awry is to specify the shapes explicitly to `@tf.function`. This helps indeed, but the python string argument stands in the way, as all `input_signature` items are supposed to be `TensorSpecs`, so in the Example 2 I remove it from the function argument list into the body of the function.¹

**Example 2**

```py
@tf.function(input_signature=[
    tf.TensorSpec(shape=None, dtype=tf.float32),
    tf.TensorSpec(shape=(1,2), dtype=tf.int32)])
def pad_last_dim(x, padding):
  mode='symmetric'
  print('=== pad_last_dim is traced.')
  ext_pad = tf.concat([tf.zeros((tf.rank(x)-1, 2), dtype=padding.dtype), padding], 0)
  x_padded=tf.pad(x, ext_pad, mode)
  return x_padded

_ = pad_last_dim(t, t_padding)
_ = pad_last_dim(t[:,:,1:], t_padding)
_ = pad_last_dim(t[1], t_padding)
print(pad_last_dim.pretty_printed_concrete_signatures())
```

```
=== pad_last_dim is traced.

 pad_last_dim(x, padding)
  Args:
    x: float32 Tensor, shape=<unknown>
    padding: int32 Tensor, shape=(1, 2)
  Returns:
    float32 Tensor, shape=<unknown>
```

Wonderful! This is exactly how I want the function to work: all three invocation reuse a single graph. But... what can I do with the `mode` argument? I want to pass it to the function (if I don't, and make it, for example, global to the module, the function won't be retraced). And I severely cannot, because specifying `input_signature` and trying to add this argument will make autograph angry at me and apoplectically red-faced.

I'm not going to bother you with all my failed attempts at achieving what I want. Making `mode` a (1,)-shaped string tensor *kind of* solves the problem, but adds a few nodes to the graph, instead of baking it as a constant input attribute to the MirrorPad op. If you wish to examine the graph, the following hack assuming a single trace of the function (note the index `[0]`) prints the graph in the textual human-readable protobuf encoding:

```py
print(pad_last_dim._function_cache.values()[0].graph.as_graph_def())
```

```
 . . . .
node {
  name: "MirrorPad"
  op: "MirrorPad"
  input: "x"
  input: "concat"
  attr {
    key: "T"
    value {
      type: DT_FLOAT
    }
  }
  attr {
    key: "Tpaddings"
    value {
      type: DT_INT32
    }
  }
  attr {
    key: "mode"
    value {
      s: "SYMMETRIC"
    }
  }
}
 . . . .
```

Is there a canonical, or a pretty kosher, or even a hacky hacky, like the well-known one using semi-public namespace to specify a `tf.Variable` argument to the traced function within the `input_signature=` list, that may help me achieve what I want? I want to leave the door open for a possible calls from the model with a different padding mode as it develops, although currently I don't.

I shall likely mention one as if obvious ‘solution’ which is not: make two copies of the function differing by the `mode` argument to `tf.pad`, like `_pad_last_dim_symmetric` and `_pad_last_dim_reflect` and call them from `pad_last_dim` based on the `mode` argument. This will not work if `pad_last_dim` is called in a tracing context, i.e. from a traceable @tf.function, possibly indirectly. While the two functions will be traced once, as desired, such a version of `pad_last_dim` will produce traces per shape of the argument `x`, like in the Example 1.

---

¹ Removing it the same way in the Example 1 did not change anything at all. Ostensibly, this isn't a Python value that confuses autograph.